# Source for blessing "Livnot Bayit Ne'eman B'Yisrael"

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, wedding

A classic blessing for a bride and groom is they should merit to build a לִבְנוֹת בַּיִת נֶאמָן בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל - a *reliable* house in Israel.

The only source I could find for this expression is the [Mi Sheberach for a Groom](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Shabbat_Shacharit%2C_Shabbat_Chatan.5?vhe=_Shaliehsaboo_Edition&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) in the Edot HaMizrach Siddurim.

#### What exactly is a  בַּיִת נֶאמָן בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל - a trustworthy house - and where does the expression come from?

In the Chumash we find Moshe being called a נֶאמָן in the [end of בְּהַעֲלֹֽתְךָ](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.8.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he) it says לֹא־כֵן עַבְדִּי מֹשֶׁה בְּכָל־בֵּיתִי **נֶאֱמָן** הוּא - Not so with My servant Moses; he is **trusted** throughout My household.

And we find Hashem being called a נֶאמָן in [the end of וָאֶתְחַנַּן](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.7.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)  where it says  הַֽ**נֶּאֱמָ֔ן** שֹׁמֵ֧ר הַבְּרִ֣ית וְהַחֶ֗סֶד לְאֹהֲבָ֛יו וּלְשֹׁמְרֵ֥י מִצְוֺתָ֖יו לְאֶ֥לֶף דּֽוֹר - there it measn he can be trusted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rav Ro”i Margolit answers the question at [yeshiva.org.il](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/12073). He says:

> המקור ל"בית נאמן" הוא בשמואל א' כ"ה כ"ח, בדברי אביגיל לדוד: "כִּ֣י
>   עָשֹֽׂה־יַעֲשֶׂה֩ ה' לַֽאדֹנִ֜י בַּ֣יִת נֶאֱמָ֗ן". והמשמעות היא בית
>   נכון וחזק העומד לדורות, כלשון איש האלוקים בדבריו לעלי (לעיל ב לה):
>   ובניתי לו בית נאמן והתהלך לפני משיחי כל הימים.
>
> The source for "בית נאמן" is in [Shmuel 1 25
>   (28)](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.25.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
>   in the words of Avigail to Dovid, “For the L-RD will grant my lord an
>   enduring house” and the meaning is “a true and strong home that stands
>   for generations” as the Man of G-d says above [2
>   (35)](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
>   “I will build for him an enduring house, and he shall walk before My
>   anointed evermore.”

I note that Rav Margolit's answer does not include the word “Israel”.